# Filter a Dataframe and then take the results and put it into a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and I want to find all rows that in the Name column have the word "hemp" in it. Once I have found these rows I want to filter these rows by just taking the name and the IOU accuracy.
From this I want to put these results into a new dataframe. However do not know how too.

```
          Name          Amount Difference  Total Pixels  \
0         hemp          68.303385         76800   
1         D2            53.333333         76800   
2         D2            67.800781         76800   
3         c2            56.917969         76800   
4         hemp          60.759115         76800   

   Area of Mycelium  Percentage Accuracy  IOU Accuracy  
0             31217            31.696615      0.193659  
1             40464            46.666667      0.119334  
2             41622            32.199219      0.102568  
3             38753            43.082031      0.244653  
4             36721            39.240885      0.138246
```

```
hemp_ilastik_df = df.loc[(df['Name'].str.contains("hemp",  case=False))]
hemp_ilastik_df2 = hemp_ilastik_df[['Name', 'IOU Accuracy']]
df= pd.DataFrame()
df.append(hemp_ilastik_df2)
```

My expected output would be:

```
          Name    IOU Accuracy          
0         hemp    0.193659        
4         hemp    0.138246
```

This however gives me an empty dataframe - I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you provide the expected output? And the input data as dictionary (`df.to_dict('list')`)

Comment: Of note, `hemp_ilastik_df2` should already be a DataFrame, what does it give you?

Comment: I have updated the question to include the expected output - and hemp_ilastik_df2 gives a dataframe but I am not sure if its just a filtered version (view) of df only as I never created an entirely new dataframe and put the results in it. When i append  hemp_ilastik_df2  to google sheets it comes up with the entire version of df

Comment: Actually dont worry i have solved it - there was an issue on my end :)